# How is it possible to create a logical drive without first creating an extended drive?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, partitioning

I was just going through [this tutorial](http://www.partition-tool.com/download/docs/convert_primary_partition_to_logical_for_creating_new_partition.swf), and in that image, he had `C:`, `H:`, `I:`, `E:` primary drives.

Then he converted `E:` into a logical drive. I was wondering how is that possible at all? Isn't it true that he had to first create an extended drive, before he can then create a logical drive `E:` within that extended drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operation of "converting a primary partition to a logical partition" seems to be a command unique to that program.  You will not be able to do that with any "Disk Management" tool provided in Windows.  Normally an Extended partition has to be created, and then logical partitions can be created.

BTW it's primary/extended/logical *partition*, not *drive*.  The "partition" is dividing up the disk drive space.  After the partition is formatted (which creates a filesystem within the partition), then you can assign a drive letter and an optional volume name.

Comment: sry I'm not understanding your last paragraph. So what's a drive? or rather, what's the difference between a "partition that is assigned a drive letter C", a "C: partition", and a "C: drive" ? Do they mean the same thing

Comment: @Pacener - I'm being pedantic.  When you're all done and using the HDD, then all three essentially mean the same thing.  But while you are creating a partition, there is no drive letter yet assigned.  Also be aware that the drive-letters assigned to partitions is a convention carried over from MS-DOS, which was originally floppy oriented.  Unix & Linux are OSes that always booted from a HDD, and don't use drive "letters" to refer to partitions.